# Hostlistener scroll event not firing

Tags: angular, syncfusion

My main goal is when user scrolls down, I need to get the current scrollTop offset. And user can scroll with mouse click on scroll bar or with mousewheel, so when user does that I want to update `take()` and `skip()` (or `page()`) parameters on **ejQuery()** to fire http get and provide data for that view.

Using SyncFusion 1

The bellow code was my try to assign a directive to **ejTreeGrid** that watches `scroll` event via **HostListener()**, but as user PierreDuc mentioned, **ejTreeGrid** implements it's custom scroller , so default one doesn't trigger. PierreDuc advised to use `getScrollTopOffset` method, but I still need to fire it everytime a user performs a scroll action...

---

A directive is being attached to SyncFusion's **ejTreeGrid** component to watch `scroll` event, but it doesn't fire. All is fine with `click` event - fires on that child component. What might be wrong?

Tried:

```
@HostListener('scrollY', ['$event'])
onScroll(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
@HostListener('onscroll', ['$event'])
onScroll2(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
onScroll3(e) {
    console.log(e)
}

@HostListener('scrollX', ['$event'])
onScroll4(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

This works:

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
onClick(e) {
    console.log('clicked')
    console.log(e)

}
```

Update:

Also added:

```
@HostListener('mousewheel', ['$event'])
onScroll5(e) {
    console.log('mousewheel')
}

@HostListener('DOMMouseScroll', ['$event'])
onScroll6(e) {
    console.log('DOMMouseScroll')
}

@HostListener('onmousewheel', ['$event'])
onScroll7(e) {
    console.log('onmousewheel')
}
```

and for some reason only `mousewheel` being fired and only when I scroll mouse wheel (obviously) but only then when scrollbar is at the top or at the bottom. Otherwise it doesn't fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TreeGrid with virtualization enabled mode **actionComplete** will be triggered with an argument requestType as **scroll** on scroll action. In this event, we can get the current scroll top position from the scrollbar instances. To enable virtualization mode, we have to set **enableVirtualization** property as true.

```
<pre>
//app.component.html 
ej-treegrid #TreeGridControl id="TreeGridContainer" 
//… 
enableVirtualization = "true" (actionComplete) = "actionComplete($event)" > 
/ej-treegrid> 

//app.component.ts 
actionComplete(args){           
          if(args.requestType == "scroll"){ 
            var treeObj = this.treeGrid.widget; 
            var scrollTop = treeObj.getScrollElement().ejScroller("scrollTop"); 
            this.scrollValue = scrollTop; 
          }
        } 
 </pre>
```

We have also prepared a sample for your reference, please find the sample from the link [Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Sample1882852977)

Answer (score 10):

Below is the working code:

```
@HostListener('document:mousewheel', ['$event'])
onDocumentMousewheelEvent(event) {
    console.log('on Mouse wheel Event');
}
```

[Please Check Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hostlisteners)

Comment: means I didn't understand ?? You want an event to be triggered by the movement of mouse wheel right ??

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the `@HostListener('window:scroll')` is not working because `style` of my body element.

It's looks like this:

```
body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

After I remove that `style`, the `@HostListener` working fine.

**Note:** So if your `@HostListener` not working, please recheck your `style` too. Make sure there's no something wrong in there.

Comment: I dont have any styles, it still not working for me

Comment: @Ismi ammar. Yes, that's why i write in my case and i write too, you have to check. If like that you can try, if not, you find another things. I am not say "it's always like this". no

Answer (score 2):

```
@HostListener('document:scroll', ['$event'])
onScroll(event) {
 console.log(event.target)
}
```

OR:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'scroll',
  templateUrl: './scroll.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./scroll.component.scss'],
  host:{
    '(document:scroll)':'onScroll($event)'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`ejTreeGrid` uses a custom scrollbar implementation. Which means there is no native scroll event being fired from that element. Perhaps you can do what you want with the [`getScrollTopOffset`](https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejtreegrid#methods:getscrolltopoffset) method on the ejTreeGrid instance.

Otherwise you can ask syncfusion for a feature that they emit a custom event on scrolling

*fyi*

To capture the mousewheel event you should use the [`wheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) event

Comment: Thanks, my main goal is user scrolls down, get the current scrollTop offset. And user can scroll with mouse click on scroll bar or with mousewheel. And when user does that I want to fire http get to provide data for that view. I know there is such `enableVirtualization`, but I failed to use it as data is being provided as `ejDataManager` with `url` and `headers` props and this object later is used as `dataSource`. So my plan is to get top offset and use on query `limit()` and `skip()` methods. How can I fire that `getScrollTopOffset` every time user perform scroll? Thanks in advance

Comment: And `wheel` event also fires only if scroll bar is at the top and I scroll up / or if scroll bar is at the bottom and I scroll down (so `deltaY` is always -100 or 100)...

Comment: Could you please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50233942/syncfusion-ejtreegrid-remove-scrollbar Many thanks