# SyncFusion ejTreeGrid - remove scrollbar

Tags: angular, syncfusion

How should I do it? It seems it uses **ejScroller** because where I use `<ej-scroller>` html being created the same, with such element:

```
<div class="e-scrollbar e-js e-widget e-vscrollbar" style="height: 622px; width: 18px;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Syncfusion TreeGrid has “auto” height support using which user can display all the records in TreeGrid without vertical scrollbar. In this case, the browser scrollbar will appear if the TreeGrid height exceeds the browser view port and this can be achieved by setting [sizeSettings.height](https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejtreegrid#members:sizesettings) property as auto. Please refer the below code snippet.

```
   <ej-treegrid id="TreeGridContainer" [dataSource]="treeGridData"
    sizeSettings.height="auto"
    //…
    </ej-treegrid>
```

We can also display TreeGrid without scrollbar and with a fixed height by using [create](https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejtreegrid#events:create), [collapsed](https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejtreegrid#events:collapsed), [expanded](https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejtreegrid#events:expanded), [actionComplete](https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejtreegrid#events:actioncomplete) client side events with some work around. Please refer the below code snippet.

```
[HTML]
<ej-treegrid id="TreeGridContainer" [dataSource]="treeGridData" 
(create)="create($event)" (collapsed)="collapsed($event)" (expanded)="expanded($event)" (rowSelected)="rowSelected($event)" (actionComplete)="actionComplete($event)"
//..
</ej-treegrid>

[TS]
  create(args) {
        /To update the height of TreeGrid during load time
         this.updateTreeHeight();
    }

    collapsed(args) {
       //To update the height of TreeGrid during collapse action
        this.updateTreeHeight();
    }

    expanded(args) {
       //To update the height of TreeGrid during expand action
       this.updateTreeHeight();
    }

    rowSelected(args) {
        //To update the height of TreeGrid while adding any row
         this.updateTreeHeight();
    }

    actionComplete(args) {
      //To update the height of TreeGrid while saving the newly added row and deleting the existing row
       if (args.requestType == "addNewRow" || args.requestType == "delete") {
            this.updateTreeHeight();
        }
    }
    updateTreeHeight=function() {
    var tree = $("#TreeGridContainer").ejTreeGrid("instance"),
        toolbar = $("#TreeGridContainer_toolbarItems").height(),
        model = tree.model,
        totalLen = tree.getExpandedRecords(model.updatedRecords);
    if (toolbar == undefined)
        toolbar = 0;
    //To calculate the height of TreeGrid as per records count
    var height = model.rowHeight * totalLen.length + tree.getHeaderContent().height() + toolbar + 4;
    //Update height using setModel
    var sizesettings = { height: height.toString() };
    tree.setModel({ "sizeSettings": sizesettings });
}
```

Please find the sample link below
http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/TreeGrid_without_scrollbar-1219686615

Regards,

Punniyamoorthi

Comment: Thanks I'll try, but as I remember I tried `auto` height and `100%` etc. I'll give you know

Comment: If the auto height feature is not suitable for your application, then you can use the second approach mentioned above. Please refer the above attached sample for the work around to remove the scrollbar in Syncfusion TreeGrid.

Comment: Thanks for help. We probably won't use TreeGrid, because it has a toolbar implemented and if I remove scrollbar and wrap TreeGrid with ejScroller that toolbar will be scrolled out on scroll (haven't tried, but I guess this would happen. Please correct me if I am wrong). So we now just play around with SyncFusion 1 (its ejTreeGrid and ejGrid) and finally will use SyncFusion2 component based on results we get. Our main goal is to get virtualScroller enabled.

Comment: In EJ1 TreeGrid, you need to wrap the TreeGrid control’s scrollable container area (#TreeGridContainere-gridcontent) with ejScroller. And if this container is attached with the ejScroller, then toolbar content and column headers will remain static while scrolling, else both the content will be scrolled if the ejScroller is wrapped with the outer container of the TreeGrid.